# Get the last selected data on dropdown when I am clicking back button using Angular15

Tags: angular, typescript

I am beginner to Angular; I need help, I have stuck in one problem.

**Scenario:** I am working on angular15, based on the requirement, I have used dropdown list, whenever selecting options from dropdown, automatically based on the first option second dropdown get populated with values. After selecting second dropdown. I need to click on submit button to navigate next page.

**Problem:** After clicking the next button or going to the next page for more info, then again, I need to go back to see the same selected option (clicking back button or browser back button)
How to see the selected options list…?

What is the method/procedure to gather the selected option…?

I have tried the router method, but it is not working.

**A.component.html**

**First Dropdown:**

```
<select #selectField class="form-select" 
                  (change)="setFieldValues(selectField.value, i)">
                  <option selected value="null" style="display: none;"> please-select</option>                     
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let field of dataFields">                        
                    <option value="{{field.name}}">{{field.name}}</option>
                  </ng-container>
                </select>
```

**Second Dropdown:**

```
<select #selectSecond class="form-select"
                      (change)="setInputsWidth(selectSecond.value, i)">
                      <option selected value="null" style="display: none;" >please-select</option>                      
                      <ng-container *ngFor="let operand of getSecond(selectField.value)">                       
                        <option value="{{operand}}"> operand</option>
                      </ng-container>
                    </select>
```

**B.component.html**

```
<button (click)="backToPageA()">Back</button>
```

**B.component.ts**

```
backToPageA(){
  this.router.navigate(["/PageA"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store values in a service which is available at the root of your application and does not get destroy.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private myData: any;

  setData(data: any) {
    this.myData = data;
  }

  getData() {
    return this.myData;
  }
}
```

Be careful, this will live forever. Which mean you might have to add logic to test the previous route used. Else you might fill the select boxes when you don't want to.